# Convert date format in returns wrong date xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to convert date from `23 May, 2017` to `23-05-2017`.

I have tried with the following code but it returns `25-12-2016`.

```
NSDateFormatter *oldFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[oldFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, YYYY"];
NSDate *oldDate = [oldFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

NSDateFormatter *newFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[newFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
```

I am using Xcode 8.2.1.
Thank You.

Comment: "yyyy" instead of "YYYY". See this: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns to find why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do below changes:

**YYYY --> yyyy**

**Updated Code:**

```
    NSString *strInputDateString = @"23 May, 2017";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];

    //Set new dateFormate
//    23-05-2017
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:strInputDateString];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSString *strOutputDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1];
    NSLog(@"%@",strInputDateString);
    NSLog(@"%@",strOutputDateString);
```